# Should i use a cronjob or stripe subscription (500 active)?

Tags: java, stripes, stripe-payments

As stripe API docs about creating a subscription

> Creates a new subscription schedule object. Each customer can have up to 500 active or scheduled subscriptions.

I want to implement with more than 500 for a customer. Should I use a cronjob to do it? With rate limiting of Stripe is 100 requests per second. Or I should create a new customer on that user to have 1000 active subscriptions and when creating a new customer the user has to enter the card information again.

Answer (score 1):

You likely don't want to be managing your own recurring invoice/payment job, but that's really up to you. Splitting into two customers is certainly less work.

Can you explain the use case for having so many subscriptions? This seems... highly unusual. You may want to write in to [Stripe support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) for assistance.

Comment: It looks like a social network. Every follows in a month is a subscription.

Comment: Would you really want to have your customer charged up to 500 separate payments each month though? Each subscription produces invoices and separate payment. This seems like a case where `quantity` on a single subscription item would be better, or if the amounts vary per "follow" then track this in your own system and roll up to quantity per tier or a custom monthly price for the calculated total amount.